# Image not contained inside of div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to contain an image inside the first div of this page and it's outside of it for some reason. All the assets are in a flexbox. It works completely fine when I put text inside that div but not an image.

I've circled in red which image and div I'm talking about. The code snippet won't show you what I'm talking about since it isn't the full code.

Here is the github repository if someone needs the full code:  [github.com/hiashley/Ashley-Yu-React-Portfolio](https://%20github.com/hiashley/Ashley-Yu-React-Portfolio)

[image][image]

```css
.landing {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}
.introWrapper {
  width: 1000px;
}

.intro1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Yapari';
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
.intro2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Yapari';
  /* font-weight: 72; */
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#introCircle {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 230px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
}
.icons {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
.icon1 {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='landing' className={styles.landing}>
      <div className={styles.introWrapper}> 
        <div className={styles.icons}>
          <img src={icon1} className={styles.icon1}/>
        </div>
        <div id={styles.introCircle}>       
          <h1 className={styles.intro1}>HELLO I'M</h1> 
        </div>       
        <LastName />
          <h1 className={styles.intro2}>A FULL STACK DEVELOPER</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For starters, try to define a height for the image (not just the width). Ultimately any `<img>` element benefits by having explicit width and height defined (in one way or another). Some browsers are picky about this. Also, the github link your post isn't clickable. If you can't provide hosting for your code then perhaps you can replicate the project in an online IDE. [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io) is really nice for quick HTML/CSS/JS replication... makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked the code, You have added Position "Absolute" to the "img" tag, That's why Image is going outside to your div. You must need to add class and then add CSS to image tag.

[View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rswLP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add style to className rather than add style to html tags directly.

Tag style is globally, module className style is locally.

[image]